# How to change value of Jtable permanently?

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans

Hi I am facing a problem that I cannot solve. I am doing this Java project of mine and I created a Jtable to display values from my database. In one of the table columns, I am setting all of its values to "pending" and I also have a button called dispatchButton that when I press this button, I want to change one of the rows value from "pending" to "dispatch" which I am unable to get it to work properly.

It is partly working as in when the dispatchButton is pressed, it will set one of the rows to "dispatched" but at the same time adding an exact copy of that same row as a new record in the Jtable. In addition, even when the value of one of the row is "dispatched" now, when I restart my application, that value is now changed back to "pending" instead of "dispatched" again. Below are some relevant code that I included for your information and testing. Do tell me of what I need to change in my code to get it to work, thank you very much.

(Note: I did not create a "status" column in the database, Im only setting the value of "status" that is in the JTable)

```
public mainpage() {
        initComponents();
        table_update();
        status_values();
        //status_dispatched();
    }
    
    Connection con1;
    PreparedStatement pst;

private void DispatchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        String type = txttype.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String name = txtname.getText();
        String quantity = txtquantity.getText();
        
        try {
            //String query = "INSERT INTO `request`(`id`, `itemtype`, `itemname`, `quantity`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/request", "root", "password");
            pst = con1.prepareStatement("insert into request (itemtype,itemname,quantity) values(?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, type);
            pst.setString(2, name);
            pst.setString(3, quantity);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item has been dispatched");
            // To update the newly recorded data to the table
            table_update();
            // To ensure that all records are still pending
            status_values();
            // Display dispatched on the row
            status_dispatched();
            
            // Set the textfields to empty upon button click
            txttype.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            txtname.setText("");
            txtquantity.setText("");
            txttype.requestFocus();
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }               

private void table_update(){
        try {
            int c;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/request", "root", "password");
                pst = con1.prepareStatement("select * from request");
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                
                ResultSetMetaData rsd = rs.getMetaData();
                c = rsd.getColumnCount();
                
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)DispatchTable.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);

                while(rs.next()){
                    Vector v2 = new Vector();
                    
                    for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
                        v2.add(rs.getString("id"));
                        v2.add(rs.getString("itemtype"));
                        v2.add(rs.getString("itemname"));
                        v2.add(rs.getString("quantity"));
                    }           
                    model.addRow(v2); 
                }
                  
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    
    private void status_values(){
        // Set all Status rows to pending
        for(int row = 0; row<DispatchTable.getRowCount(); row++){
            DispatchTable.setValueAt("Pending", row, DispatchTable.getColumn("Status").getModelIndex());
        }
    }
    
    private void status_dispatched(){
        // Upon the click of the Dispatch button, the status of that row should be dispatched
        String dispatch_row = txtdispatch.getText();
        int convert_dispatch_row = Integer.parseInt(dispatch_row);
        DispatchTable.setValueAt("Dispatched", (convert_dispatch_row)-1, DispatchTable.getColumn("Status").getModelIndex());
    }
```

Comment: *but at the same time adding an exact copy of that same row as a new record in the Jtable. * it looks to me like you "insert" a new row into your database. You should "update" an existing row. * when I restart my application, that value is now changed back to "pending" instead of "dispatched"* - I don't see where you ever "update" the status in your database. Using the setValueAt(...) method of the JTable will NOT update the database.

Comment: @camickr I did not create a status column, in the database, it has no relation to it at all, the only relation is has is to do with the JTable

Comment: So why would you expect the table to remember the previous value when you load all the data from a database? Unless you have a rule that can set the status based on values in the database you will always lose this information unless you have some method of storing the data.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the table have a permanent value? I don't wish to set the value based on the database as I can't find a reason to do so, I only want to change the status value once the button is pressed

Comment: But the button won't be pressed the next time you start your application. So your application has no way of knowing that you have previous pressed the button, unless you  somehow store that information locally in your application. And this doesn't make sense since the data in your database can change and it is not a good idea to store data in two places since it can easily get out of sync.